# How to get post content by get_posts function?

Tags: plugin-development, get-posts

I'm newbie at Wordpress and now I need to get the post content in events plugin. I have simple array:

```
$event = get_posts(array(
          'name' => $events_array[$i],
          'post_type' => 'events',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'numberposts' => 1
        ));
        $events_array_id[] = $event[0]->ID;
    }
```

but I don't understand, how to get content there. Thanks for help.

Comment: can you please write more details about what you want achieve here , coz if u only need to get content of post you only use `the_content()` function inside the loop

Comment: I need to get contents for each post, which display on my page.

Comment: Is it correct?

`$event = get_posts(array(
'name' => $events_array[$i],
'post_type' => 'events',
$post_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
'post_status' => 'publish',
'numberposts' => 1
));
$events_array_id[] = $event[0]->ID;
}`

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly want to do, `the_content` function display the content for the post but must call inside the loop. if this page like archive page display some posts (like I understand), so you need 1- get all posts you need to an array (like you doing in question) 2- to display `$event` array you need create loop first (google it) 3- Inside loop you can use `the_content` easily